# How to scroll to first error inside a Spring form?

Tags: forms, spring, validation, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

My registration is using Spring forms and validates the data after submit, the form:errors will be printed out if there are errors. I need to scroll the page down to the first form:error so the user hasn't to search for the error, is there a way to do that?

cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried any of them, but I can think of two possible ways:

- With Javascript. Spans generated by < form:errors /> have a class (I don't remember at the moment) or you can force on using cssClass attribute. Would be very easy using [this](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/) jQuery plugin to scroll to the first one.
- Without Javascript. This will be a lot more difficult and I'm not sure it will work:

  - In your controller, instead of returning a direct view you must do a redirect to something like */myForm#error*.
  - In order to don't lose your model, you must use FlashMap attributes.
  - "Subclass" < form:errors /> tag. It must have the same behavior but it has to include an anchor named error on the first error of the page.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it with anchors. -- But you need to implement it by your own.

My idea it to put anchors on all input files. And then have some java script that is able to scoll to an anchor. This java script is invoked on page load if the error object contains errors. -- This errors contains the name of the field. So if you have some schama for naming the anchors it should be possible to invoke the jump to an anchor script with the name of the field hat has an error.